# images not found but only in certain situations

Tags: image, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have an area of a website that has a few broken images; however it is only in a few different situations.

**Where it works**

- Windows 7 (all 64 bit) - Chrome, Firefox, IE7, IE8, IE9
- Windows XP - Firefox, Chrome

**Where it doesn't work**

- Windows XP - IE8, IE7

If I look in the source on the Windows XP/IE combinations, the generated source looks fine. However, if I paste the URL of the image into the address bar, sure enough it can't find it despite it being there. If I copy and paste the same URL into one of the other browsers, it finds it just fine. Cross browser quirks is something we are all familiar with, but an image not being found but only in certain hardware/software combos is certainly a new one for me.

Comment: Can you provide an example?   And/or post the HTML markup?

Comment: Sure! http://www.cjsfireplaces.com/acatalog/Contemporary_Fireplaces.html. Notice as well it's not like it is all images either.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is 3 years old, and the images are no longer there, but anyone investigating this problem may have some luck with this answer:
[Some images won't display in IE7 or IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313466/some-images-wont-display-in-ie7-or-ie8?rq=1)

Short version: the images are CMYK compressed rather than RGB; apparently it can be fixed by opening in irfanview and re-saving it, or something similar in photoshop.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Amended to have a short explanation of the link